Warn me when I approach areas known to be flooded / have pools of water during/after rain
When driving on roads in the United States during or after rains, I'm always very concerned about the presence of large pools of water on the roads, especially on highways. I've seen this happened in both California and Washington, and this is a major danger, especially at night when the roads are dark (since lights are barely used in the US on roads). I'm therefore looking for a phone application that could warn me when I approach areas known to be flooded / have pools of water during/after rains. Any license or price is fine.
